# PyAudio Record until exit

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I don't have enough knowledge about Pyaudio and I couldn't find it on the net. I want the script run until I stop it and when I stop, it must save recording. The sample code from Pyaudio records for a fixed time.

Comment: Have a look at my example [rec_unlimited.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use error handling to save the audio once you have a keyboard exception, (in this case pressing something like `Ctrl +  C` to end the program.

```
While True:
    try:
        recording_function()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        save_function() #record to a file
    except: 
        #generic error processing
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. How can I handle termination? I found atexit but it doesn't handle termination

Comment: how are you terminating the script? Is it a button or someother method?

Comment: with a  button or directly closing window

Comment: with a button use the onclick handler in whatever GUI Framework you have, otherwise use `atexit` to serve as an exit handler (https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html)